# Connection Android client to a TCP C# server

Tags: java, c#, android, tcp, server

I created a simple server code that accept multi connection and read a string (command) from the client, where my client is a simple android application that should send a request type like "GetListFoods"

I have succeed to make the connection but the process stopped in the part where the server should read the request (server side) and cannot complete its work.

I am pretty sure about my server side code but I am new android programmer.

Here is my Server Side code :

```
public class Server
    {
        private int _Port;
        private TcpListener _Listener;
        private bool _Listening = false;

        public Server()
        {
            _Port = 5050;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, _Port);

            _Listener.Start();

            _Listening = true;

            _Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAcceptTcpClient, _Listener);
        }

        private void HandleAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            if(_Listening)
            {
                _Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAcceptTcpClient, _Listener);
                TcpClient client = _Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);

                ClientConnection connection = new ClientConnection(client);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(connection.HandleConnection, client);
            }
        }
    }
```

the connection class is just a simple class that handle the client request:

```
 class ClientConnection
    {
        internal TcpClient _controlClient;
        private NetworkStream _controlStream;
        private StreamReader _controlReader;
        private StreamWriter _controlWriter;

        public ClientConnection(TcpClient client)
        {
            _controlClient = client;
            _controlStream = _controlClient.GetStream();
            _controlReader = new StreamReader(_controlStream);
            _controlWriter = new StreamWriter(_controlStream);
        }

        public void HandleConnection(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                string line;
                while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = _controlReader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    //Make Some work here
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I need to make a simple request from my Android application,
here is my code :

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConnectToServer server = new ConnectToServer();
                server.execute("GetList");
            }
        });
    }

    public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in;
        Socket client;

        public ConnectToServer() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                //byte[] message = params[0].getBytes();
                client = new Socket();
                client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("X.X.X.X", 5050));
            } catch (UnknownHostException host) {
                host.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                out.write(params[0]);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the question? It's not clear to me what issue are you facing.

Comment: how to make it pass the line readLine() and return the value of the request to parameter line, because it is blocked there without reading anything @PrerakSola

Comment: try  out.println(xx); out.flush(); on client.

Comment: I have already tried the out.flush() but the problem didn't change, so I will try the out.println() , @GaryYKim

Comment: Thanks a lot @GaryYKim , out.println() make it :)